# Is there a formula to turn ease in pow function into ease out?

Tags: math, interpolation, algebra

I have a control that's used as an exponent in a pow function. This changes the values in an ease in fashion. Is there a way to turn this into an ease out mathematically?

I know for example, ease in cubic is:

```
pow(t, 3)
```

but ease out cubic is:

```
(pow((t - 1), 3)) + 1
```

and ease out quart:

```
   float t = t2 - 1
   -(pow(t, 4) - 1)
```

So the formula changes quite a bit, and I need a generic way so I can use values like 4.2, 9.7, as the exponent etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For integer exponents this is called Hermite interpolation.

---

One can also interpret this task as an application of the chinese remainder theorem in polynomial rings

```
f(x) == 0 mod x^p
f(x) == 1 mod (x-1)^p
```

The solution has the form

```
f(x) = a(x)*x^p+b(x)*(x-1)^p  with  deg a(x) < p, deg b(x) < p.
```

Inserting into the second equations gives

```
a(x)*x^p == 1 mod (x-1)^p  <=>  a(y+1)*(y+1)^p == 1 mod y^p
```

which can be solved via binomial series, i.e., direct power series arithmetics without solving linear systems of equations,

```
a(y+1) = 1 - p*y + p*(p+1)/2*y^2 - p*(p+1)*(p+2)/2*y^3 +-... ...*y^(p-1)
```

---

For non-integer exponents, why would you want to do that?

---

Also look up "sigmoid functions".

---

**Update**

If continuity of derivatives is not so much a concern then for any positive `a` you can use `c*x^a` for `0<=x<=0.5` and `1-c*(1-x)^a` for `0.5<=x<=1`. To close the gap at `x=0.5`, the constant has to be chosen such that

```
1 = 2*c*0.5^a  <=>  c = 2^(a-1)
```

which can be implemented for `0<=x<=1` as

```
y = (0.5>x) ? 0.5*pow(2*x,a) : 1-0.5*pow(2*(1-x), a);
```

Comment: Thanks alot, very helpful. Basically I want a normalized value to be modified via an exponent if wanted. But I also wanted to give the ease out version of it. Using exponents this way is useful but it's always a float in the apps I used. So in your first code, is it if mod(x, 2) == 0, etc? I tried this one: http://paste.ofcode.org/39dE6zyDnZ5xwWEu9viRszA

Comment: I do not understand your `mod(x,2)` expression. I have added how you can get a power function go through (0.5,0,5) and make it symmetric relative to this point.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I meant like modulo with 2 to see if the exponent is odd or even. I thought that's what your first code did.

Comment: I pasted some code here that shows the progression. If you notice the ease in always uses pow(value, exponent) while the ease out alternates between 2 different forms depending on if the value is odd or even. This why I thought maybe there is a way to generalize it. Someone told me to use matrices but not sure if it would help me. http://paste.ofcode.org/SCPe6pyZyAsnX7CuZtNZpq

Comment: For the ease out you can always use `1-pow(1-t,exponent)`, this is always the same as your formulas. However, for `t=0.5`, or any other `t`, you get a gap between both functions, you can not switch between them without a jump. That is the reason for the scaling in my formulas.